# How do albums affect chart ranking of singles?

Tags: album, charts

Just a random thought I had.

I was wondering if album purchases counted towards the position of singles contained within on the chart rankings.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billboard_Hot_100 I must admit I am to lazy to read it all, but maybe you can find your answer there...

Answer (score 1):

Album purchases do not count towards the position of singles, certainly on the US and UK album charts, anyway.

Factors that do count:

- airplay
- sales of singles
- online streaming
- airplay of remixes
- sales of EP's